# Trying to make read from excel function

Tags: javascript

I'm just making a offlne money exchange website/app.
I have all the up to date currency rates on an excel file.
I want to make javascript that reads the excel file and duplicates the money amount according to the user wanted amount.
I'll be happy if someody will give me a direction how to do it or even write the script for me.

Thank you (:

Comment: load the rate into a variable with AJAX, and do your math.

Comment: can you send me a script?

Answer (score 0):

Use [`fgetcsv`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php) to parse as and return it to browser as json.

```
<?php

// required for browser to recognize the content as JSON (IF) you choose the AJAX way
// header('Content-Type: Application/json');

$rates = []; // empty array

$file = fopen('path/to/rates.csv', 'r'); // open file

// loop over each row (line) 
while (($line = fgetcsv($file)) !== FALSE) {
   $rates[] = $line;
}

@fclose($file); // close file to save memory 

// print JSON string
$ratesJSON = json_encode($rates);
```

You can use the above code as inline script or request it over AJAX.

```
<?php
 // that code above
?>
<html>
    <head>
       ...
    </head>
    <body>
       ...
       <!-- Other content of page -->
       <script>
          var rates = <?php print $ratesJSON; ?>;
       </script>
    </body>
<html>
```

Comment: how do I put it into a html script?

Comment: @mastercoder, I am going to need more details. What is your server-side language? If it's PHP (most widely used; that's why I used it), you can save the file as index.php, and upload it to server.